# TFT Monitor output is blurry and weird looking - but OSD works fine

Tags: monitor

I don't really know how to describe what happened to my monitor, but I made a small video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjh5crE-Zx4).

In summary, the output of the monitor is all garbled, but still there (not dead) - but the OSD works fine.

I have some knowledge of electronics - so I opened it up, checked the capacitors, didn't find anyone gone bad - but I'll check again, might have missed something.

Any pointers as to how could this happen, and where should I focus my investigation? I guess it's something related to the VGA input, but what could it be? (So I should check only the vga board, not the power one?)

I should note that I have another, identical monitor (it was a part of a dual-display setup): If I remove the faulty monitor and connect the good one, everything is fine - so it can't be the PC or the VGA or the cable, something has gone wrong in this particular monitor.

Comment: Are you sure it's the monitor?  Try it connected to a friend's computer / laptop to check it's not the computer.  Alternatively try a different monitor on the computer.  It's quite likely it's the graphics card on the computer that's failed.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins I'm sure its the monitor. I have another, identical monitor, and if I connect it it displays fine. I'll edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Have you tried a different VGA cable?

Comment: @W5VO, yes, with another cable too. The problem is in the electronics of the monitor. Also, if I just unplug the vga cable from the faulty monitor and connect it to the second identical good one, everything works fine.

Comment: If you like, you can swap boards between your two identical monitors. Without touching your good monitor: Does your bad monitor have different inputs (analog/DSUB, analog/BNC, digital/DVI)? If so, does the problem occur at all the inputs? I'm asking because I guess not. I assume the fault is likely in some early stage around the analog input. Could be its power supply, could be a bad capacitor in the signal (series connected), could be the part of the circuit that tries to figure out the VSYNC. Or, as has been suggested already, a bad contact or via around the connector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bad pin - one of the syncs (either horizontal or vertical).  According to [pinouts.ru](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15_pinout.shtml) this could be either pin 10,12, or 13 (sync ground, horizontal or vertical sync).  If you can swap cables on your monitor try that.  If you can and that doesn't help, it's the connector on the monitor.  You could try to replace it - aim a heat gun at the connector and pull it when all the solder melts or use a hot air rework station or a solder wick, then replace it.  You can buy right angle HD-15 connectors like [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=A35119-ND) one on Digikey or elsewhere.  Remember - it's a high-density 15 pin D-sub connector, female, through-hole and probably right-angle.  Should be cheap if that's the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, I've already changed the VGA cable once, no changes with that. One idea I had yesterday was that maybe there is a fault with the LVDS cable. Could it be? Nice idea about the D-sub connector, I have to try that!

Comment: Nope.  Good OSD means good LVDS connection.